# Query struct propreties from solidity to reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity

I want to call function propreties from a smart contract to my API and i dont know how to do it.

the smart contract function is

```
 Function getFile(uint id) external constant returns (string, string) {
      file storage F = files[id];

      return (F.description, F.hash);
    }
```

Do any one know what is the syntaxt to extract the description and hash values for specific file using the getFile(id) in the API?

```
<p> The description is {this.state.description} and the hash is {this.state.hash} </p>
```

Thank you !